# Actionscript 3.0 - Sort an array positive distance to a specific point

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array full with numbers, that are not in any order, and I need the number in that array that is the closest to another specific number, but not bigger than it. For example:

```
someArray:Array=new Array(-10,-5,2,2.7,30,46,123.56,231,320);
somenumber:Number=50;
```

Now i need an algorithm that is the fastest way to get the 46 out because it is the closest to 50, but not bigger than it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work - just iterate through each number in the array, and find the largest one that is less than or equal to your target:

```
var closest:Number = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for each(var num:Number in someArray)
{
  if(num > closest && num <= somenumber) {
    closest = num;
  }
}
// now the variable closest has your answer
```

If you array is guaranteed to be sorted, then you can do some sort of a binary search type algorithm which would run in log time instead of linear time.

Comment: You answered my question, but I honestly don't know what your talking about with a binary search algorithm using log time. If you could  explain that, because i like to learn things, then that would be appreciated, but if not then I guess i'll learn that when i go to college.

Comment: So, say our array has _n_ elements. Our algorithm is linear time, because it looks through all _n_ elements once. A log time algorithm, in general terms, has log(_n_) steps, which for large numbers is much faster than _n_ steps. 

Wikipedia has an example of how a binary search works in a real-life type scenario - the number guessing game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Number_guessing_game